# Calculate mahalanobis distance

Tags: c++, opencv

From a bunch of images `I`, a mean color `C_m` evolves. Now I want to obtain a distance image, using mahalanobis distance, in which each pixels mahalanobis distance to the `C_m` gets calculated. I can't get OpenCV's `Mahalanobis()` function to work.
I calculate the calcCovarMatrix with all pixel colors of `I`, invert it and pass it to `Mahalanobis()`. Next I'm looping over the new image to calculate the distance for every single pixel:

```
  Mat covar, incovar, mean;
  calcCovarMatrix(...);
  invert(covar,incovar,DECOMP_SVD);

  for (int row = 0; row < image.rows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col < image.cols; ++col) {
            Scalar color = image.at<Vec3b>(row, col);
        double m_dist = Mahalanobis(color, mean, incovar);
        }
  }
```

Resulting in:
`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == v2.type() && type == icovar.type() && sz == v2.size() && len == icovar.rows && len == icovar.cols) in Mahalanobis, file /tmp/opencv-8GA996/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp,`

What's my mistake here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Mahalanobis](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mahalanobis) is not working on single pixels, but on whole images. so instead try :

```
double dist = Mahalanobis( image1, image2, invcovar );
```

Comment: Ok, so I guess I have to code up my own function to do my task of getting the distance between a mean color and the actual pixel color. I go to the point of doing so, because this was written in a paper: "Visual inspection of the Mahalanobis distance per pixel be- tween the second frame and the road model built from the first frame reveals that some of the color transforms will per- form better than others". Where the road model just consists of the mean color.